# Delete button deletes the row but not from the database,how do i correct it?

Tags: angular, mysql-error-1064, angular2-services

I have a datatable which updates deletes adds new event,i have successfully implemented the get function but i am unable to perform post,put,delete.
Any help would be appreciated.

my datatables.ts file:

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import {FadeInTop} from "../../shared/animations/fade-in-top.decorator";
    import { Http } from "@angular/http";
    import { DemoService } from "app/+tables/+datatables-showcase/datatables.service";
    import { Task } from "app/+tables/+datatables-showcase/tasks";


    @FadeInTop()
    @Component({
      selector: 'sa-datatables-showcase',
      templateUrl: './datatables-showcase.component.html',
    })
    export class DatatablesShowcaseComponent implements OnInit {

    allTasks:Task[]=[];



      constructor(private _demoService:DemoService) {}

      ngOnInit() {
        this._demoService.getAllTasks().subscribe(
          (data:Task[]) =>{
            this.allTasks= data;
          }
        );

      }

  deleteTask(item:Task){
      this._demoService.deleteTask(item.ActivityID)
      .subscribe(
        (data:any) =>{
          this.allTasks.splice(this.allTasks.indexOf(item),1);
        },
        function(error){
          console.log('complete');
        }
      );
    }



  }
```

datatables.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions } from "@angular/http";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Task } from "app/+tables/+datatables-showcase/tasks";

@Injectable()
export class DemoService {
    public url: string = "http://localhost:3000/Tasks/";

    constructor(private _http: Http) {
    }

    // Uses http.get() to load a single JSON file
    getAllTasks() {
        return this._http.get(this.url)
            .map((response: Response) => response.json());
    }




    deleteTask(item: Task) {
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

        return this._http.delete(this.url + item.ActivityID, options)
            .map((response: Response) => response.json());
    }

    addTask(item: Task) {
        let body = JSON.stringify(item);
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        return this._http.post(this.url, body, options)
            .map((response: Response) => response.json());
    }

    editTask(item: Task) {

        let body = JSON.stringify(item);
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        return this._http.put(this.url + item.ActivityID, body, options)
            .map((response: Response) => response.json());
    }
```

}

task.ts

```
export class Task {
    constructor(
        public ActivityID: any,
        public Title: String,
        public ActivityCode: String,
        public Status: string,
        public ActivityDesc: String,
        public DeptID: String,
        public Idate: String

        ) {
    }
}
```

datatable-showcase.component.component.html

```
<div id="content">
  <div class="row">
    <sa-big-breadcrumbs [items]="['Table', 'Data Tables']" icon="table" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-7 col-md-7 col-lg-4"></sa-big-breadcrumbs>
    <sa-stats></sa-stats>
  </div>

  <sa-widgets-grid>


    <div class="row">
      <article class="col-sm-12">


        <sa-widget [editbutton]="false" color="darken">
          <header><span class="widget-icon"> <i class="fa fa-table"></i> </span>
            <h2>Standard Data Tables</h2>
          </header>
          <div>
            <div class="widget-body no-padding">
              <sa-datatable [options]="{
                colReorder: true,

              columns: [ {data: 'ActivityCode'}, {data: 'ActivityDesc'},{data: 'DeptID'},{data: 'Idate'}  ] }"
                paginationLength="true" tableClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" width="100%">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <th data-hide="phone">Activity Code</th>
                    <th data-class="expand"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-user text-muted hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs"></i> Activity Description
                    </th>

                    <th data-hide="phone"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-phone text-muted hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs"></i> Department
                    </th>

                    <th data-hide="phone,tablet"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-map-marker txt-color-blue hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs"></i> Idate
                    </th>
                    <th data-hide="phone,tablet"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-calendar txt-color-blue hidden-md hidden-sm hidden-xs"></i> delete
                    </th>
                    <th data-hide="phone,tablet">View</th>




                  </tr>


                </thead>
                <thead>
                <tr *ngFor="let item of allTasks">
                  <td>{{item.ActivityCode}}</td>
                  <td>{{item.ActivityDesc}}</td>
                  <td>{{item.DeptID}}</td>
                  <td>{{item.Idate}}</td>
                  <td><button (click) ='deleteTask(item)' type="button" class="btn-btn-default" aria-label="Left Align">
                    <span class = "glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden = "true"></span>
                    </button>
                  </td>
                  <td><button (click) ='deleteTask(item)' type="button" class="btn-btn-default" aria-label="Left Align">
                    <span class = "fa fa-edit" aria-hidden = "true"></span>
                    </button>
                  </td>

                </tr>

                </thead>
              </sa-datatable>

            </div>
          </div>
        </sa-widget>






      </article>


    </div>

  </sa-widgets-grid>
</div>
```

My Server side page Task.js in Models

```
var db = require('../dbconnection');

var Task = {

    getAllTasks: function (callback) {

        return db.query("Select * from Track_tblActivityMaster", callback);

    },
    getTaskById: function (ActivityID, callback) {

        return db.query("select * from Track_tblActivityMaster where ActivityID=?", [ActivityID], callback);
    },
    addTask: function (Task, callback) {
        console.log("inside service");
        console.log(Task.ActivityID);
        return db.query("Insert into Track_tblActivityMaster values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", [Task.ActivityID, Task.DeptID, Task.ActivityCode, Task.ActivityDesc, Task.WriteUP, Task.AFgrpID, Task.Idate, Task.Icreater, Task.IsActive, Task.IsDelete], callback);
        //return db.query("insert into task(Id,Title,Status) values(?,?,?)",[Task1.Id,Task1.Title,Task1.Status],callback);
    },
    deleteTask: function (ActivityID, callback) {
        return db.query("delete from Track_tblActivityMaster where ActivityID=?", [ActivityID], callback);
    },
    updateTask: function (ActivityID, Task, callback) {
        return db.query("update Track_tblActivityMaster set DeptID=?,ActivityCode=? ActivityDesc=? WriteUP=? AFgrpID=? Idate=? Icreater=? IsActive=? IsDelete=?    where ActivityID=?", [Task.DeptID, Task.ActivityCode, Task.ActivityDesc, Task.WriteUP, Task.AFgrpID, Task.Idate, Task.Icreater, Task.IsActive, Task.IsDelete, ActivityID,], callback);
    },
    deleteAll: function (item, callback) {

        var delarr = [];
        for (i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {

            delarr[i] = item[i].Id;
        }
        return db.query("delete from Track_tblActivityMaster where ActivityID in (?)", [delarr], callback);
    }
};
module.exports = Task;
```

Tasks.js in Routes

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Task = require('../models/Task');

router.get('/:ActivityID?', function (req, res, next) {

    if (req.params.ActivityID) {

        Task.getTaskById(req.params.ActivityID, function (err, rows) {

            if (err) {
                res.json(err);
            }
            else {
                res.json(rows);
            }
        });
    }
    else {

        Task.getAllTasks(function (err, rows) {

            if (err) {
                res.json(err);
            }
            else {
                res.json(rows);
            }

        });
    }
});
router.post('/', function (req, res, next) {

    Task.addTask(req.body, function (err, count) {

        //console.log(req.body);
        if (err) {
            res.json(err);
        }
        else {
            res.json(req.body);//or return count for 1 & 0
        }
    });
});
router.post('/:ActivityID', function (req, res, next) {
    Task.deleteAll(req.body, function (err, count) {
        if (err) {
            res.json(err);
        }
        else {
            res.json(count);
        }
    });
});
router.delete('/:ActivityID', function (req, res, next) {

    Task.deleteTask(req.params.ActivityID, function (err, count) {

        if (err) {
            res.json(err);
        }
        else {
            res.json(count);
        }

    });
});
router.put('/:ActivityID', function (req, res, next) {

    Task.updateTask(req.params.ActivityID, req.body, function (err, rows) {

        if (err) {
            res.json(err);
        }
        else {
            res.json(rows);
        }
    });
});
module.exports = router;
```

Please let me know where i am going wrong.
Thank you.

Comment: Please post datatables-showcase.component.html

Comment: Hey Nikunj Ratanpara ,datatables-showcase.component.html is added please check and let me know

Comment: Are you sure that your query is correct?

Comment: i feel so,if it isn't please correct me.

Comment: Hey Nikunj  i have added my server side code,please check and let me know where i have made mistake.